# please help me to know the error in this code

Tags: vba, excel-formula, listbox, userform

I would like to find out the error in this code. When applying the code using the IF and else rule, it applies to the first condition only and ignores the second condition, labs is a label.

```
Dim ww As Double, z As Double, s As Double, n As Double, j As Long
On Error Resume Next
ww = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox5.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("users").Range("y2:z1000"), 2, 0)
With ListBox1
     For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

   If .List(j, 8) <> "" Then z = z + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                                      s = s + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                                      n = n + ListBox1.List(j, 6)
If ComboBox5.Value <> Labs2.Caption Or ComboBox5.Value <> Labs3.Caption Or ComboBox5.Value <> Labs4.Caption _
    Or ComboBox5.Value <> Labs5.Caption Then
         t11.Value = s
   Else
         t11.Value = z
End If
    tx3.Value = n
    Frame61.Visible = False

    Labs7.Caption = ComboBox5.Value`your text`
    Next j
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

I want to modify this code to apply if and else rule.

Comment: Is your intention to have the `z =` line AND the `s =` line AND the `n =` line to all be part of the `If`? Is that why you have them indented? Because right now, the `If` only applies to the `z =` - The indentation is irrelevant.

Comment: Wrapping the whole code in `On Error Resume Next` will not help your troubleshooting/debugging.  You should only apply that where needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `Or` all those tests for `ComboBox5.Value` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it works on the first condition only, even if I change the type of the condition. My question is why does it not respond in case of error and give the second condition, or if there is another code that applies the required

Comment: yes i need all this tests for or

Comment: Please use useful titles here - the title here doesn't tell readers what the problem is. Titles should be a short summary of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my notes on your code in the comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Data_To_All_SubFiles()
        
    Dim ww As Double
    Dim z As Double
    Dim s As Double
    Dim n As Double
    Dim j As Long
    
    ww = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox5.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("y2:z1000"), 2, 0)
    
    With ListBox1
        For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            
            
            ' > You might have a  problem here, the way this is written _
                it looks like you want "s = s..." and "n = n..." to be _
                dependant on your ".List(j, 8) <> """ condition. _
                Currently, these will always run. If you want them dependant, _
                then write it like this:
                    'If .List(j, 8) <> "" Then
                    '   z = z + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                    '   s = s + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                    '   n = n + ListBox1.List(j, 6)
                    'End if
            If .List(j, 8) <> "" Then z = z + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                                             s = s + ListBox1.List(j, 6) * ww
                                             n = n + ListBox1.List(j, 6)
                                             
                                             
            ' > All these "Or"s mean, unless Labs 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the same, _
                it will always return true, I'm not sure what your logic is _
                but you either need "And"s or you need to change those _
                "<>" signs to "=" signs
            If ComboBox5.Value <> Labs2.Caption Or _
                ComboBox5.Value <> Labs3.Caption Or _
                ComboBox5.Value <> Labs4.Caption Or _
                ComboBox5.Value <> Labs5.Caption Then
                    t11.Value = s
            Else
                t11.Value = z
            End If
            
            tx3.Value = n
            Frame61.Visible = False
            
                                    ' Whats this? \/
            Labs7.Caption = ComboBox5.Value `your text`
        Next j
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Z is meant by the sum of column 6 in the listbox, provided that the addition of what corresponds to the blank in column 8 in the listbox is excluded.
S is the sum of column 6 in the whole listbox without conditions
These are the only two that are required to be achieved in the  if else